# Deciphering which COB LED used in a circuit

Tags: led-driver, constant-current, cob

I have two lamps with identical LED circuits. The lamps sometimes blink when turning on. One of the lamps already has a blown COB LED. I suspect the wiring was done wrong. I've opened it up, but I still don't fully understand what I'm measuring and seeing.

The output driver is a constant 300ma current with a voltage range of 24-36 volts. The measured voltage on the working lamp using a multimeter is 37.5 volts (measured between the + and - terminals of both COB LEDs). That explains the blinking as the output driver is turning off due to over-voltage.

What I can't figure out is why I'm measuring 37.5 considering that the output driver should drive 300mA (not measured). The circuit is the output driver with a single black & red set of wires. I believe the COB LEDs are hooked up in parallel.

The output driver is: 120v AC .15A 60Hz, output is 300mA, 24-36v.
The COB LEDs are Edison, and I believe it is either of these (based on some identifying marks):
http://www.edison-opto.com/en/product/edipower_v_he_series
http://www.edison-opto.com/en/product/edipower_v_hm_series

There are 13 visible LEDs on each COB, so I believe they are the first grouping of LEDs with these specs:
Absolute Max Ratings 6.75W (input power), 180mA (dc forward current) - this leads me to believe max voltage is 37.5v. And therefore the resistance is 208 ohms.
One of the LED types has forward current as 90mA, and forward voltage as (32.1, 34.9, 37.7).
The other has forward current as 90mA, and forward voltage as (31.2, 34, 36.8).
But with these numbers I still can't figure out why I'm measuring 37.5 across both LEDs. I would expect that the resistance is half of 208 ohms which is 104 ohms. But at 104 ohms with a current driver of 300ma (constant current of output driver), shouldn't the voltage be: 31.2?

It makes me wonder if my assumption of 300mA is wrong - even though the output driver is a constant current output driver.

Comment: ohms don't always fit neatly into the equation when junctions are in play, especially with heat confounding the variables. 37v out of a 36v driver is probably normal, they are not lab-grade supplies. I would bet that if you cool the LED better, the current will drop and the safety mechanism won't blink the output anymore.

Comment: The lamp only flashes on and off when it's first turned on (and rarely at that). It never really happens after a while. That makes me wonder whether heat dissipation has anything to do with this.

Comment: interesting. Still not sure if i get the question. forget about ohms with LEDs; going from 3.0v to 3.1v can double the current in some situations, so that nice linear ohm's law won't help you much.

Comment: It is electrically correct to use a 24-36v 300mA constant current driver with 2 of these COB LEDs? http://www.edison-opto.com/get.php?f=Edison+Opto_EdiPower®+V+2PHM03xWxxP32020_Eng_V1.pdf&s=Edison+Opto_EdiPower®+V+2PHM03xWxxP32020_Eng_V1.pdf&path=doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LED's datasheet you linked to seems to indicate V[f] ~ 38V @ 150mA. So, when two of the LEDs are connected in parallel to a driver, and the driver tries to force 300mA through them, it would have to output about 38V, give or take. It seems the driver, trying to force 300mA to the LEDs, just maxes out at 37.5V (and probably below 300mA) because it cannot output more voltage than that (maybe limited by the input voltage it gets), or it achieves the 300mA by going 1.5V above the specified output voltage.

So I'd say it's not "electrically correct" to use a "300mA @ max. 36V" constant current driver in a setup which requires about 38V @ 300mA. It's probably constantly overloading the driver and will cause premature failure. (Would have to check the driver's datasheet if it is tolerable/recommended for the device to operate in this condition.)

Comment: What’s the calculation that arrives at 38v @ 150mA?

Comment: Top chart on page 11 of the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks! That was a missing piece for me.